# Restore database function not restoring properly

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, restore

I've written the following code to allow a user to restore the latest backup of the system that was made.

```
  Private Sub RestoreLastBackupToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RestoreLastBackupToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim tr As OleDbTransaction = Nothing

    Try
        Dim confirmBackUp As MsgBoxResult
        confirmBackUp = MsgBox("Are you sure? This will restore the database to the previously backed up version", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")

        If confirmBackUp = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then  Else Exit Sub
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

        con.Close()

        Dim rCon As New OleDbConnection("My connection string is in here")

        rCon.Open()
        tr = rCon.BeginTransaction()

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE MaintenanceControl SET Single_user WITH rollback immediate; DROP DATABASE MaintenanceControl;"
        cmd.Connection = rCon
        cmd.Transaction = tr
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd = New OleDbCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE MaintenanceControl FROM DISK='c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MaintenanceControl.bak'"
        cmd.Connection = rCon
        cmd.Transaction = tr
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Database Restored", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Success")
        tr.Commit()
        rCon.Close()
        openCon()

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        MsgBox("Could not restore database, refer to error log")
        tr.Rollback()

    End Try
End Sub
```

The issue with this code is that when the database is restoring (After being backed up to the same path, it doesn't restore the latest version of that database, it's restoring a different version. When closing and re-opening the application, it still isn't using the correct version, and the only way to get the correct version (the latest backup), is to restore it by using the Restore function in SQL Server itself.

Why is not restoring properly? Is there something that I've missed or done wrong?

Comment: What messages/diagnostics are being reported? (You'll need to switch to `SqlConnection` etc. and subscribe to the [`SqlConnection.InfoMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event.) Also don't forget to take the database out of single user mode.

Comment: @Richard there are no errors or issues with the above code, the only issue is when using other parts of the system, the error is "Key not found" since the database that is being restored doesn't have some of the new columns that were in the backed up version. What do you mean by switching to `SqlConnection`?

Comment: Re. `SqlConnection`: using the SQL Server specific ADO.NET types gives better access to SQL Server functions (and you're doing SQL Server specific actions so no loss in generality).

Comment: Re. "key not found": am I correct to summarise as "restored to older version of database, application expects new version, and application fails"? If so then you need to restore to a version of the database that supports the expectations of the application. Or build your application to be tolerant of older database schema versions.

Comment: @Richard The backup that it should be restoring is a different version, for some reason. When I use SQL Server itself to restore the same file, it works fine, so it's something to do with it finding an older version and restoring that, I think